# Proper way to use visitors in ANTLR4 (javascript target)

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4

I am having trouble understanding how to properly use Visitors in ANTLR4, Javascript target.

I have prepared a very basic grammar, it accepts `INT + INT` or `INT - INT` operations.

```
grammar PlusMinus;
INT    : [0-9]+;
WS     : [ \t\r]+ -> skip;

PLUS  : '+';
MINUS : '-';

input : plusOrMinus
    ;

plusOrMinus
    : numberLeft PLUS numberRight # Plus
    | numberLeft MINUS numberRight # Minus
    ;

numberLeft : INT;
numberRight : INT;
```

From this grammar ANTLR will generate a Visitor that has these three functions, `visitInput`, `visitPlus` and `visitMinus`. I start from `visitInput` where I will be able to fetch the operation ctx by doing this `operation = ctx.plusOrMinus()`.

This is where I get stuck, how do I know if `operation` is of type plus or minus? In other words, where do I pass `ctx.plusOrMinux()`, to `visitPlus()` or `visitMinus()`?

I managed to create a visitor that does work, but it's very ugly, [I am posting it here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6b388afff93da12cbb2d) because perhaps it will help to better understand my question. Lines 20-29 is where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all... PLUS and MINUS are lexer rules.  You don't visit tokens (the result of lexer rules).

It rather looks like you're expecting this to work like a listener (where you set up your function that gets called when the tree walker reaches that node.  You can be called on enter or exit from the node (depends on whether you want to get the node before or after you've processed it's children).  Visitors expect you to handle your own tree navigation, which is sometimes useful, but listeners are cleaner where they suit the purpose.  With nesting, You'll probably want to listen after the children nodes are processed, so you'll want to implement an exitPlusOrMins() function on your listener.  I'd suggest stopping your code in the debugger inside this function to take a look at the objects you have available to you (in the ctx object).

(You also need to rethink your numberLeft and numberRIght parser rules.  Something more like:

plusOrMinus: lexpr=INT (op=PLUS | op=MINUS) rexpr=INT;

would give you a pretty close equivalent to what you have so far. What you have will work with a recursive descent parser like ANTLR (so far as this example goes), but you're headed in the wrong direction making them different parse rules.  Specifically, by making them two alternative parse rules, you're giving PLUS a higher precedence than minus, and PLUS and MINUS should have the same precedence in order of evaluation.  As a result, they need to be the same parse rule.). When you place alternatives like this in a parser rule, you're also establishing precedence, so be careful about the order of these rules.

To get further than adding or subtracting integers, though, you'll need lexpr and rexpr to actually be expressions themselves (you should read up on expression parsing in the ANTLR book; it's covered very nicely).

With that rule, your exitPlusOrMinus can parse the int values of lexpr and rexpr and then evaluate the value of the op to determine whether to add or subtract.